# Install door handles on opposite sides of a pocket door

Tags: doors, screws, drill, pocket-door

I am new to DIY and bought some custom door handles; I'd like to install them on both sides of a pocket door, but I'm not sure how. I asked the manufacturer for an installation guide, but they haven't gotten back to me.

The handle has two holes, one for a `1/8"` screw and one for a very small metal dowel, about `1/32"` wide and `3/8"` long.

The `1/8"` screw is `1 7/8"` long and goes in `1/4"` deep into the handle. It has a cap nut that covers `1/4"` of the other end, and a washer that is `1/32"` wide.

The `1/32"` dowel is `3/8"` long and goes in `1/8"` into the handle.

My door is `1 3/4"` thick.

I'd like to install handles at the same height and mirrored orientation on both sides of the door; it seems like I could do that by drilling a single hole through the door and using a dowel screw `1/4" + 1 3/4" + 1/4" = 2 1/4"` long, but I'm not sure that would work. On the other hand, I don't want to have the fastener for the screw showing on the opposite side of the door, which would also prevent installation in a mirrored conformation.

Pictures of the assembly below:

[image: Back of the handle]

[image: Side view of the handle with the screw & metal dowel inserted]

Comment: Is your door hollow? How can you have protruding handles on a pocket door, btw?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Exactly what I was wondering. I thought the whole point of a pocket door is that it slid into the wall.

Comment: Installing that handle on the door will prevent it from sliding all the way open. You need a recessed handle that will sit _inside_ the thickness of the door in order for it to operate.

Comment: You got a "custom" handle set, but custom for what application? Look at videos on how pocket door handles are supposed to work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you’ve got the wrong type of door hardware. Pocket door pull handles is like this:

https://www.rejuvenation.com/catalog/collections/pocket-door-pull/products/5977ec6101925b619487597b?cm_ven=PLA&cm_cat=Google&cm_pla=default&cm_ite=C4017&gclid=CjwKCAiAyc2BBhAaEiwA44-wWwjZiKLZl6cZuvH4-hMghtLEze3cgeAgOheeq_23q20v5e0mF4F7gxoCerQQAvD_BwE

You can Google “pocket door hardware “ and you’ll see many styles to choose from.

Comment: If the poster does not need the latching (locking) function, then there are handles without that.